# LINQ Contains() with list of string

Tags: c#, linq

How do I pass a list of strings to contain?

```
var test= _context.TableName.Where(e => e.type == "icon" && e.Code.Contains("list of string"));
```

Regards

Comment: it should be `IEnumerable<string>.Contains(string)` ... it should work with LINQ but of course it may not work with EF

Comment: What about turning things around and doing `"list of strings".Contains(e.Code)`?

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing the details it is somewhat difficult to suggest something but you could just do it in the opposite way:

```
var test = _context.TableName.Where(e => e.type == "icon" && listOfString.Any(e.Code.Contains));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough

```cs
var setOfStrings = new HashSet(){"string1", "string2"};
var test = _context.TableName.Where(e => e.type == "icon" && setOfStrings.Contains(e.Code));
```